Want to convert object value to array and combine
I want to convert object value to array and if in array it has same value for one key then want to combine that both objects.
For example below in data, I am getting "Id" as normal value, but I want to convert it to array.
Also if you see for Date : 20241205 I have two different objects so I want to make combine all of them.
Sample data :
"schedule": [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Date": 20241201,
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Date": 20241202,
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Date": 20241205,
    },
    {
        "Id": "4",
        "Date": 20241205,
    }]

Want this output :
"schedule": [
    {
        "Id": ["1"],
        "Date": 20241201,
    },
    {
        "Id": ["2"],
        "Date": 20241202,
    },
    {
        "Date": 20241205,
        "Id": ["3","4"]
    }]

I am trying to use assign method.

What did you try? Pleaseshow us your attempts.

use Object.groupBy
